# When $C = \begin{pmatrix} A & \mathbb{1} \\ \mathbb{1} & B \end{pmatrix}$ is posdef?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, block-matrices

Consider a matrix $C$ of the form:

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
A & \mathbb{1} \\
\mathbb{1} & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where all the blocks ($A,B$ and the identity matrices) are square and of the same size, and the matrices $A,B$ are symmetric and positive definite.

For context, I encountered a matrix of this form as the Hessian of a certain function for which I am trying to determine the conditions for a critical point to be a minimum.

Suppose I can find the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ separately. Can I exploit this knowledge to conclude that $C$ is posdef in some conditions?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728917/eigenvalues-of-block-matrix-beginpmatrix-a-mathbb1-mathbb1-b

Comment: No, take $A=I=B$ it will not work, you could manage it if your eigenvalues ar sufficiently big maybe? with the subordinate norm

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I understand $C$ is not always posdef. The question I am asking is whether there is a condition on the eigenvalues of $A,B$ and their eigenvectors such that $C$ *is* posdef.

Comment: Yes I added a specification

Comment: Does $1$ mean $I$?

Comment: @coiso That's right.

Comment: The block matrix is positive definite if and only if all eigenvalues of $AB$ are greater than $1$. So, a sufficient (but not necessary) condition is given by $\lambda_\min(A)\lambda_\min(B)>1$.

Comment: @user1551 Can you prove this statement? That is, that $AB-I$ must be posdef.

Comment: @a06e $C$ is congruent to the direct sum of $A$ and $B-A^{-1}$, the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $A$ in $C$. Therefore, $C$ is positive definite iff $B-A^{-1}$ is positive definite, i.e., iff $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\succ I$. In turn, it is equivalent to $\lambda_\min(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})>1$. As this eigenvalue is identical to $\lambda_\min(AB)$, the result follows.

Comment: You know, you can also check the answers when you ask a question

Comment: @user1551 Ok so $C$ is posdef iff $AB-I$ is posdef. That's a nice characterization, thanks.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Thanks, I see you have edited your answer and it now contains proof of user1551 comment.

Comment: I understand now that the eigenvalues of $A$ or $B$ alone are not enough to state anything on $C$ because the "orientation" of $A$ relative to $B$ is also important.  I have to study the product $AB$. This is okay.

Comment: @a06e No, the necessary and sufficient condition for $C$ to be positive definite is *not* that $AB-I$ is positive definite, but that $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}-I$ is positive definite. We only speak of the definiteness of Hermitian matrices, but $AB-I$ is not necessarily Hermitian.

Comment: @user1551 I meant that the eigenvalues of $AB-I$ are positive.

Answer (score 1):

Take $Z = \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \end{pmatrix}$

$$Z^* C Z = X^* A X + Y^*BY + X^*Y + Y^*X$$

But Cauchy-Schwarz gives us
$$|X^*Y + Y^*X| = \left| \begin{pmatrix}Y \\ X \end{pmatrix}^* \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \end{pmatrix}\right| \leqslant \left\| \begin{pmatrix}Y \\ X \end{pmatrix} \right\| \left\| \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} \right\| = \|Z\|^2$$

And
$$\|Z\|^2 = \|X\|^2 + \|Y\|^2$$
so
$$Z^* C Z \geq X^* A X + Y^*BY - \left( \|X\|^2 + \|Y\|^2 \right)$$

If you ensure $\forall \lambda \in \operatorname{Spec} (A) \cup \operatorname{Spec} (B)$, $\lambda >1$, you get
$$Z^* C Z >0$$

So you have $C$ definite positive hermitian matrix.

The condition on the spectrum is not necessary. An example was given in the comments. We could maybe refine the proof to get the condition:
$$\min \operatorname{Spec} (A) \cdot \operatorname{Spec} (B) >1$$

---

**Refinement**
Replace $X$ by $X'=\sqrt{A}^{-1}X$ and $Y$ by $Y'=\sqrt{B}^{-1}Y$ in the previous identity (it is equivalent), you get
$$Z'^*CZ' = X^*X + Y^*Y + X^* \sqrt{A}^{-1} \sqrt{B}^{-1} Y + Y^* \sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{A}^{-1} X$$

But since they are complex numbers,
$$\left(X^* \sqrt{A}^{-1} \sqrt{B}^{-1} Y\right)^* = \overline{X^* \sqrt{A}^{-1} \sqrt{B}^{-1} Y} = Y^*\sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{A}^{-1} X$$

So
$$f(Z) = Z'^*CZ' = X^*X + Y^*Y + 2\Re \left(Y^* \sqrt{AB}^{-1} X\right) $$

Now you can study this to find the minimal value. Its gradient is
$$df_Z (H) = \begin{pmatrix} 2\Re(X^*H + Y^* \sqrt{AB}^{-1} H) \\ 2\Re(Y^*H + X^* \sqrt{BA}^{-1} H) \end{pmatrix}$$

$df_Z = 0 \iff X = -\sqrt{AB}Y \text{ and } Y =- \sqrt{BA} X $

If we continue the study, it will be equivalent for $f(Z)>0$ if $Z \neq 0$ and for $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ to have eigenvalues $>1$, and equivalently for $AB$ to have eigenvalues $>1$.

Comment: You can easily generalize it with other matrices than identities.

Comment: Also I used the hermitian context but feel free to change ${}^*$ by ${}^T$

Comment: The condition on the spectrum is not necessary: for $2\times 2$ matrix the necessary and sufficient condition is $ab>1.$

Comment: Yes for $n=2$ but I don't know for $n$ bigger

Comment: Your refined condition is still not necessary. The block matrix in the OP is positive definite if and only if all eigenvalues of $AB$ are greater than $1$.

Comment: @user1551 I did not say it was necessary, I can see why such a condition would emerge, but prove it? Plus my answer may suit him better since he may not want to compute $AB$